# Iterating over a vector of structs and dereferencing the iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, dereference

I'm iterating over a `vector` of `struct`s, and then trying to dereference the iterator. I think I'm missing some bit of logic and doing it wrong, or just don't get the syntax right.

The code is as follows and contains a lot of debug output:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


using namespace std;


int main()
{
    ifstream fin("gift1.in", ios::in);
    ofstream fout("gift1.out", ios::out);

    unsigned short NP;

    struct person
    {
        string name;
        unsigned int gave;
        unsigned int received;
    };

    vector<person> accounts;

    string tmp_name;

    fin >> NP;
    accounts.resize(NP);
    for (auto& i : accounts)
    {
        fin >> tmp_name;
        //fout << "Just read this name: " << tmp_name << "\n";
        i.name = tmp_name;
        i.gave = 0;
        i.received = 0;

    }

    fout << "\n";

    for (unsigned int j = 1; j <= NP; j++)
    {
        string giver_name;
        fin >> giver_name;
        fout << "Read a name #" << j << ": " << giver_name << "\n";

        auto vpit = find_if(accounts.begin(), accounts.end(), [&giver_name](const person& pers) -> bool {return pers.name != giver_name; });
        if (vpit == accounts.end())
        {
            fout << "Couldn't find this giver in accounts\n";
        }
        else
        {
            person& found = *vpit;  // the logic is probably wrong here
            fout << "\nDebug info: \n\t Giver#" << j << "; \n\t iterator->name ==" << vpit->name << "; \n\t iterator->gave == " << vpit->gave << "; \n\t iterator->received == " << vpit ->received << "\n";
            fout << "Found " << found.name << " in accounts; proceeding\n";
            //further code
    }
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: What is the problem? Please describe the question to the text not in the code. Please indent your code.

Comment: The `iterator->name` stays the same. But it's expected to change, since the `find_if` is expected to find the respective `persons`s.

Comment: It's not necessary to provide in and out modifiers to ifstream/ofstream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find an element of the vector with the given value then you have to use the equality operator

```
auto vpit = find_if( accounts.begin(), accounts.end(), 
                     [&giver_name] (const person& pers) { return pers.name == giver_name; } );
```

As for me then the second loop

```
for (unsigned int j = 1; j <= NP; j++)
{
    string giver_name;
    fin >> giver_name;
    //...
```

looks questionably.

Comment: Changed it, and it seemingly works that way. Which should mean that my iterators were OK, but my comparison wasn't?

Comment: @Chiffa As I have understood you need to find an element with the given value. In this case the element will be found when the condition is true that is then the corresponding elemnt's data member is equal to the given value.

Comment: That's right, it is. Thanks. I'm now solving some other problems with the logic of the other parts of the code, not mentioned in this question.